# When does single TCP channel is not sufficient in Azure service bus, Redis cache, Queue etc

Tags: sockets, tcp, redis, azureservicebus, azure-redis-cache

I have seen this kind of recommendation at multiple places, such as:

> Multiple factories: all clients (senders in addition to receivers) that are created by the same factory share one TCP connection. The maximum message throughput is limited by the number of operations that can go through this TCP connection. The throughput that can be obtained with a single factory varies greatly with TCP round-trip times and message size. To obtain higher throughput rates, you should use multiple messaging factories.

You can find similar recommentations for Redis, RabbitMQ etc. My question is, how does one TCP channel can get exhausted? I believe that there is no bandwidth limitation on a single TCP channel.

So, Why people suggest to have multiple channels for high throughput? Is it because:

1. In case, client application sends lots of small messages to a single tcp channel, each operation will take a lock on tcp socket and then sends the message. It can result on lock contention. And if we use multiple tcp channel, this contention could be resolve to some extent.
2. In case a large message is send on tcp channel, it can take some time to serialized/de-serialized and pushing it to channel. It can block other small messages.

Are these the actual reasons (or in case these assumptions are wrong, what are the real reason)?

Answer (score 1):

Basically, you're right.
Client 1 --> TCP/IP ---> Server (Do some processing)
Now, Client 2 want to send request to server? Client 2 will need to wait for Client 1 finish (I assume the context here is about blocking I/O). So, if you have more than one TPC connection, Client 2 can send request simultaneously with Client 1 ==> increase throughput.
But it come with cost to maintain more active connection. You should make sure you have "enough" connection to serve your request and also minimize the number of  "idle" connections.

Comment: It doesn't increase throughput. It increases parallelism. The network only has so much bandwidth, and sending two things at once instead of one shares it, so can only use 1/2 each.