# One TCP connection limit

Tags: tcp, tcpclient

Generally people suggest to use multiple TCP connections to increase the throughput (in multithreaded scenario). Is there any kind of limit on how much data (or how many different packets) can be traveled on one TCP connection?

Thanks In Advance

Comment: There is no limit. I'm unable to see the connection between your question and your first sentence. Adding parallel connections has limited effect.

Comment: If there is not limit on one TCP connection (even if it is shared among multiple threads for sending/writing data ), why to create multiple connection to increase the throughput

Comment: The fact that there is no limit on the number of packets or amount of data doesn't have anything to do with throughput whatsoever, unless you take time into account, which you didn't mention in your question. There is of course still a bandwidth limit on the entire path to the target, which does affect throughput. Howeevr there is very little point in creating multiple connections to the same data, unless they operate over different paths. Your question doesn't really make sense.

Comment: Ok, Let me add some more context to it. While accessing redis cache, azure service bus or RabbitMQ, it is recommended to use multiple object (that wraps TCP connections) inside them. Here is a similar question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39247311/when-does-single-tcp-channel-is-not-sufficient-in-azure-service-bus-redis-cache

Comment: In other words this is a [duplicate question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/39247311/207421).